# How to iterate Oracle Query Cursor field in PHP?

Tags: oracle11g, php-7

I hope you can help me, I need to get the data of an SQL query in Oracle 11g, which one of its fields is cursor type, this is the query:

```
SELECT m.nombre, m.icono, (CURSOR(SELECT p.nombre nombre_permiso, p.url
                                FROM permiso p 
                                WHERE p.fk_menu = m.pk_menu 
                                AND p.estado = 'A'
                                ORDER BY p.orden)) permisos FROM menu m WHERE m.estado = 'A' ORDER BY orden;
```

When I execute it with PHP, the field namepermiso appears as a ResourceId type, but it should give me the fields it contains, I suppose that is the type of field, the PHP code I use is the following:

```
$sql = "DECLARE
                    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
                BEGIN
                    OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT m.nombre, m.icono, (CURSOR(SELECT p.nombre nombre_permiso, p.url
                                                      FROM permiso p 
                                                      WHERE p.fk_menu = m.pk_menu 
                                                      AND p.estado = 'A'
                                                      ORDER BY p.orden)) permisos
                    FROM menu m
                    WHERE m.estado = 'A'
                    ORDER BY orden;

                    :cursor := my_cursor;
                END; ";

        $conn = $this->db->conn_id;
        $curs = oci_new_cursor($conn);
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":cursor", $curs, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
        oci_execute($stid);

        oci_execute($curs);
        while (($row = oci_fetch_array($curs, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) 
        {
            var_dump($row);
        }

        oci_free_statement($stid);
        oci_free_statement($curs);
```

The var_dump show this:

```
array(3) { ["NOMBRE"]=> string(16) "Parametrización" ["ICONO"]=> string(11) "fa fa-gears" ["PERMISOS"]=> resource(46) of type (oci8 statement) } array(3) { ["NOMBRE"]=> string(24) "Gestión de información" ["ICONO"]=> string(10) "fa-sitemap" ["PERMISOS"]=> resource(47) of type (oci8 statement) }
```

thank you very much!